# Dual Feedback Transistor Biasing -- Confusion on Equations

Tags: bjt

[image: Circuit and Equations]

Looking at the equations above, I understand almost everything except for what I_B1 represents, I had a guess of it being the base current, but that is represented as I_B in other equations. So I am just a bit confused.

I also wanted to ask assuming I_B1 is equal to I_B, does the following equation accurately find the voltage at the base?

I_B = (V_B - V_BE)/R_B2

Comment: \$I_{B1}\$ is the current flowing through \$R_{B1}\$, apprently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$I_{B1}\$ is a typo, it's \$I_{RB1}\$, as the current through \$R_C\$ is the sum of the collector current \$I_c\$ plus the current through \$R_{B1}\$.